# TomEE Internal JMS on MySQL

Tags: java, activemq-classic, apache-tomee

I use this config for use TomEE JMS with mysql .
[According to OpenEJB Document](http://openejb.apache.org/jms-resources-and-mdb-container.html)

```
    <Resource id="MyJmsResourceAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
            BrokerXmlConfig =  broker:(tcp://localhost:23250)
            ServerUrl       =  tcp://localhost:23250
            DataSource      =  mysql
    </Resource>
    <Resource id="mysql" type="DataSource">    
            JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver   
            JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/activemq    
            UserName root    
            Password rootpass    
            JtaManaged true    
    </Resource>
```

My questions are:

1. How does this `MyJmsResourceAdapter` work? Does JMS use MySQL for queue messages?
2. What about database tables? (I could not find any documentation about that.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. it will just instantiate a ActiveMQResourceAdapter with the values you configuired (or defaults). You will find some explanations on http://tomee.apache.org/admin/configuration/resources.html.
2. the persistence (and most of the bahvior to be fair) is then fully delegated to activemq 5, you can find the mysql information at http://activemq.apache.org/jdbc-support.html. If you want to see how it is implemented and why you don't need the ddl you can have a look to https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-jdbc-store/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/store/jdbc/adapter/MySqlJDBCAdapter.java which handles the tables initialization.